# Issues with Messages Customer Community page (Direct Messages)

Tags: customer-community

I am attempting to set up Direct Messages in my Customer Community. I have been able to sucessfully set up everything (using the [documentation listed here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_direct_messages.htm&type=5)) except the Messages page (Item 6, bullet 1 of the referenced document). When I try to add the Messages page to the navigation bar, I receive the following error message:

```
The URL for My Messages requires one or more parameters. 
Please replace each parameter with the appropriate value.
```

I've looked into this issue and understand that the "/:recordId" part of the hyperlink needs to be changed. My question is how to make this hyperlink dynamic, so that it references the messages of the user who clicks the link, rather than a specific user's link.

An alternative workaround for this that would also work would be to find another way for users to access their entire Direct Message history in the Customer Community. The Message Notification component only shows the three most recent Direct Message threads, which is not sufficient for our purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution - replace the "/messages/:recordID" text with "/messages/Home". Now when a user clicks on this page they will be directed to their own entire message history.

[image]